# Upgrade to 4.6.6 : how to configure mysql server?

Tags: mysql, configuration, performance

I upgraded Civicrm to 4.6.6 (next 4.6.7) and had a lot of problems since then. My sql server has started consuming much more memory while everything was allright before the upgrade with 512M of RAM.
After the upgrade, the server crashed because it was overconsuming memory. It never happened before. I lowered the values (of cache and tmp tables). I had then a issue with max connections reached. I restarted the server several times and try to find the good configuration but no success for now.
What is a fair configuration of mysql server with drupal 7 and civicrm 4.6.7?
Does anyone has an idea why the upgrade made this problem occur ?
Thanks a lot
Laure

Comment: Do you mean that the server running MySQL has only 512M available, or that MySQL itself is configured to use only 512M?

Comment: I am seeing a similar problem after upgrading to 4.6.8.   Memory usage warning and then mysql crashes.   No dashlets of any significance.

Comment: Correction - cpu load warning before crash

Comment: DaveT, sounds like mysql is killed because of high memory use elsewhere (likely apache child processes).

Answer (score 1):

A lot depends on how much data you maintain in terms of contacts, participants, members, etc.

I have seldom seen any recent install of CiviCRM (on Drupal 7) running well on anything less than 1 gig, and I always recommend at least 1.5 gig; usually 2 gig.

Sorry, but I suspect no amount of MySQL tuning is going to give you what you need with only 512M.

Answer (score 0):

what was the version you were using before?

the user interface is moving to be more reactive, and it means more smaller ajax requests than a big page loaded once in a while, it might have an impact.

an issue i faced is the dashlets that tend to generate a lot of requests too, try to ask your users to remove them, see if things improve.

as for the suggested size, i don't know, our servers are not vpn, so we got an order of magnitude more memory than your configuration.